# Strange search terms automatically added to Search Query table

Tags: magento2, search, query, advanced-search

Strange search terms appear in **Last Search Terms** and **Top Search Terms** which are from **Search Query** table.

[image]

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have checked the access log at `/var/log/apache2/access.log`
2. I found that SemrushBot, AhrefsBot, and PetalBot was making the connections.
3. I have added the below content to the custom instruction of robots.txt File at the
   **Content-->Design-->Configuration**

   ```
   User-agent: PetalBot
   Disallow: /

   User-agent: SemrushBot
   Disallow: /

   User-agent: AhrefsBot
   Disallow: /
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It could be possibly because of a search module or any custom functionality. BTW which Magento 2 version are using.?

Comment: it was because of bots.